# How to send to multiple endpoints in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1,
I wish to log the transaction details after response back to client.
For that I have written Proxy as well as sequence but wso2esb-4.8.1 is not supporting that with send mediator ,because I want t use load balance for every endpoint where as same logic is working in CallOUt mediator with URL option not with address endpoint .

## proxy

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test_Proxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
<description/>
<target>
<inSequence onError="FaultSeq">
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<log>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="ProxyInRequest" 
expression="/soapenv:Envelope"/>
</log>
<xquery key="ProxyRequestTransformation">
<variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Operation" expression="//Operation/text()" type="STRING"/>
<variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceNameSpace" expression="//ServiceNameSpace/text()" type="STRING"/>
<variable name="Payload" type="DOCUMENT_ELEMENT"/>
<variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceName" expression="//Service/text()" type="STRING"/>
</xquery>
<send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/test1" format="soap11"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence onError="FaultSeq">
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
<property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<send/>
<sequence key="AuditSeq"/>
</outSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL key="EaiEnvelope"/>
</proxy>
```

In above proxy i have used default send mediator after that trying to do audit in same flow ,My client is getting response back but details are not auditing even not getting any error.

## My sequence

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AuditSeq"> <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="RESULT_CODE" expression="get-property('ResultCode')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="RESULT_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ResultMessage')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="REFERENCE_ID" expression="get-property('ReferenceID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="FAULT_DETAILS" expression="concat(get-property('ERROR_CODE'),get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
<open:processRequest xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
<aud:Auditor xmlns:aud="http://jhm.kkk.fff/Auditor">
<aud:Request>
<aud:Operation_Name>processRequest</aud:Operation_Name>
<aud:Auditor_InputData>
<aud:Result_Code>$1</aud:Result_Code>
<aud:Result_Message>$2</aud:Result_Message>
<aud:Reference_Id>$3</aud:Reference_Id>
</aud:Auditor_InputData>
</aud:Request>
</aud:Auditor>
</open:processRequest>
</format>
<args>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_CODE')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_MESSAGE')"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('REFERENCE_ID')"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
<header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://www.openuri.org/processRequest"/>
<send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService" format="soap11"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
<log>
<property name="aftersend" value="message going out or not"/>
</log>
</sequence>
```

With above send mediator is not working .But after send my log is printing.
If i replace send mediator with CallOut URL option its working fine.

```
<callout serviceURL="http:///localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService">
<source type="envelope"/>
<target key="IsThisResponse"/>
</callout>
```

In above we are not able to use loadbalancing.For that I trying for send mediator.
Is any way to do this.
I thouhgt wso2esb-4.8.1 is become stable but again its having drawbacks.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing the send mediator in your proxy as mentioned here it may help you

```
<send receive="AuditSeq">
  <endpoint>
  <address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/test1" format="soap11"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.But as per your guidance it will go to audit sequence but before that i want to send response back  to client.what u told it will send not  response to client it will receive in audit after that give the response back